# Replace few variable names in the string for c#

Tags: c#, for-loop, replace

I have a question, my template content does not have a fixed value, this template content value is random and comes from what the user input and stores in the table, but the variable of the content is set.

For example few template content values (For **schedule.TemplateContent**) :

```
1. My name is {name}.
2. My name is {name}. My last name is {lastName}
3. Her name is {name}. She is a {sex}. She like play {activity}
```

Below is my code, I just only know how to replace 1 word in the template content, not sure how to replace if loop the template content has multiple variables need to replace:

```html
foreach (SAASQueuePatList pat in patList)
{
pat.PatName = "{name}";
pat.PatLastName = "{lastName}";
pat.PatSex= "{sex}";
pat.PatActivity = "{activity}";

string fullContent = schedule.TemplateContent.Replace("{name}", pat.PatName);
}
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string fullContent = schedule.TemplateContent
    .Replace("{name}", pat.PatName)
    .Replace("{lastName}", pat.PatLastName)
    .Replace("{sex}", pat.PatSex)
    .Replace("{activity}", pat.PatActivity);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a map that links a field name to a property.

```
var map = new Dictionary<string,Func<SAASQueuePat,string>>
{
    "name", x => x.PatName,
    "sex", x => x.Gender
};
```

Then you can generate string like this:

```
foreach (var item in map)
{
    template = template.Replace("{" + item.Key + "}", item.Value(pat));
}
```

Comment: Wu Can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74345867/date-time-range-if-crash-the-some-date-time-range Thank you