# Date Time range if crash the some date time range

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a problem writing the condition to set the appointment date in C#

For example:

If I want to make the Date & Time of the Appointment start on 07 Nov 2022 11:30 AM, and end appointment date time will be 07 Nov 2022 02:30 PM.

But in the HR organizer has set the lunch hour as 1pm - 2pm. The start form 07 Nov 2022 and end date is 11 Nov 2022.

So the result should be cannot make an appointment.

Sample UI for an appointment:

[image: 1]

Sample UI for Schedule Organizer:

[image: 2]

I try to write the condition query to detect if the appointment DateTime is crashed in the schedule organizer.

Below is my sample coding, but cannot work:

```html
if ((DateTime.Parse(currentStartDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <=  DateTime.Parse(currentDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) && 
DateTime.Parse(currentDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <= DateTime.Parse(currentEndDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) &&(DateTime.Parse(currentAptStartTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) >= DateTime.Parse(currentStartTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) &&
DateTime.Parse(currentAptStartTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <= DateTime.Parse(currentEndTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) && 
(DateTime.Parse(currentAptStartDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) >= DateTime.Parse(currentStartDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) && 
DateTime.Parse(currentAptStartDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <= DateTime.Parse(currentEndDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
{
return false;
}else
{
return true;
}
```

Variable sample value:

```html
currentAptStartTime = "07 Nov 2022 11:30 AM"
currentAptEndTime = "07 Nov 2022 02:30 PM"
currentStartTime = "1pm"
currentEndTime = "2pm"
currentStartDate = "07 Nov 2022"
currentEndDate = "11 Nov 2022"
```

May I know how to properly or good practice to write the condition to meet the above requirements? Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Firstly, there is _way_ too much Parsing going on, there.

Comment: @Fildor Do you have good practice to implement this?

Comment: And if you have two Timespans s1-e1 and s2-e2, then they do not collide if s1>e2||s2>e1, given that s1 < e1 and s2 < e2. (Adjust for allowing the edges to collide for example s2 == e1)

Comment: Prevent fiddeling with strings representing a DateTime so you never have to parse back and forth? In most UI frameworks the controls know about DateTime so you never should have the need handling them as string.

Comment: _"Do you have good practice to implement this?"_ Well, store parsed values instead of parsing them x times.

Comment: You are parsing same fields multiple times. First you should create DateTime fields and parse the inputs only once. And also this if can be split in multiple statements. No point to have the second comparison if first fails.

Comment: @Fildor Okay, can you write down the sample query on how to store parsed value

Comment: Like `var startDate = DateTime.Parse(strStartDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` and then go on to work with startDate ...

Answer (score 0):

You can extract a method which will do all the parsings:

```
    private static bool TryMyParse(string text, out DateTime result) {
        return DateTime.TryParseExact(
            text,
            new[] { //TODO: put all the accepted formats here
                "h tt",    // Today + provided time
                "h:m tt",  // Today + provided time
                "htt",     // Today + provided time 
                "h:mtt",   // Today + provided time
                "d MMM yyyy",
                "d MMM yyyy h:m tt",
            },
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal,
            out result);
    }
```

Then you can use it as: parse the dates and allpy your logic

```
if (TryMyParse(currentStartDate, out var dtCurrentStartDate) && 
    TryMyParse(currentEndDate, out var dtCurrentEndDate) && 
    TryMyParse(currentDate, out var dtCurrentDate) &&
    TryMyParse(currentAptStartTime, out var dtCurrentAptStartTime) &&
    TryMyParse(currentAptStartDate, out var dtCurrentAptStartDate)) {
     // Dates are valid, your logic comes here

     return !(dtCurrentStartDate <= dtCurrentDate && 
              dtCurrentDate <= dtCurrentEndDate &&
              dtCurrentAptStartTime >= dtCurrentStartTime &&
              dtCurrentAptStartTime <= dtCurrentEndTime && 
              dtCurrentAptStartDate >= dtCurrentStartDate && 
              dtCurrentAptStartDate <= dtCurrentEndDate);
}
else {
    // at least one date is of wrong format
}
```